# Alexa Country Code "0"

Tags: alexa-internet

I'm using Alexa to get Top Country and Top Country Percent.  One of the country codes I'm getting back is "0" and I don't see any documentation for what this is.  When I spot-check individual sites so far I've either found that the country with the most traffic is either unknown or US.  Anyone have any ideas on what "0" means as a response?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant 'O', and not '0'.Am I wrong? 

If so, "O" means Other (=countries except US in your example).